# Is it normal for the identity of a host to change after enabling SSL?

Tags: ssh, ssl, ssl-certificate, authentication

1. I logged in to a known host - `ssh username@example.com`.
2. I did `a2enmod ssl` and I generated a CSR to enable SSL on one of the virtual hosts on the server.
3. From a separate terminal tab, I tried to do an `scp` to the same host.

At this point, the server responded with:

```
The authenticity of host 'example.com (123.123.123.12)' can't be established.
```

Given the context, is this normal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has nothing to do with SSL.

Why you should get the warning from scp is a different matter.  Assuming the hostname is exactly the same as when you SSHed, perhaps you are using `scp` as a different user or from a different host (or using `sudo`, which means you will be using root's known_hosts file).

To verify the fingerprint, you can use `ssh-keygen -l -f` with the public keys on the known host.

Comment: Thanks. It's the same user at the same host. Based on your instructions I did `ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and it showed a different fingerprint. What should I do?

Comment: Your comment seems cut in half.

Comment: It was! (SF & Parcelite)  ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub is the client public SSH key.  I meant for example, on example.com, `ssh-keygen -l -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub` (will be different if you've negotiated ECDSA).  This should match the fingerprint that either scp or ssh ask you to confirm.  

`ssh` and `scp` should share the same `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file, so I can't explain why you get the warning when using scp.

Comment: Thanks! It does match the fingerprint that scp asked for.

Comment: "I can't explain why you get the warning when using scp" - I can't explain that either. Could you give me some directions as to what I should do to make sure that the host is not a target of an attack?

Comment: You can also from your local machine run `ssh-keygen -F example.com -l` to check if you have a stored fingerprint for example.com.

Comment: Well, if you actually had physical access to the server and ran `ssh-keygen -l -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub` and it matches the fingerprint scp, then that indicates no MITM attack.  So just keep a record of that fingerprint, and when you first connect from a different host (or as a different user) and check it matches.  You weren't perhaps using one of scp or ssh with sudo?

Comment: I did, for some reason, use `sudo` for the `scp` in question when I got the problematic response about the authenticity of the host. Could that `sudo` be the reason for it?

Comment: Yes.  If you used `ssh` without sudo, it will store the host fingerprint int /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts.  Then when you `sudo scp` it will instead check in /root/.ssh/known_hosts.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! You've been quite helpful. I appreciate it. Do you do freelance work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21343/discussion-between-cedric-knight-and-emanuil-rusev).

Comment: I sent you a message in the chat.